# Gulp: Copying files from A to B while keeping case-senstive folder-names

Tags: javascript, gulp, case-sensitive

I want to create a gulp-task that takes files from all folders named "foldertocopy" and copies them to some output directory.

Imagine the following file-structure:

- Root
- - js
- - - foldertocopy
- - css
- - - FOLDERTOCOPY

My gulp-task looks like this:

```
return gulp.src('./Root/**/foldertocopy/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Root2'));
```

The copying itself works perfect. But all copied folders are called "foldertocopy" (while some of them should be called "FOLDERTOCOPY").

How can I make sure the case is kept while copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the pattern in your `gulp.src` is [`glob`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#globs) style so in you can pass second parameter to the `glup.src` in which define the `glob` flag

in your case i think this code should work

```
return gulp.src('./Root/**/foldertocopy/**/*.*',{nocase:true})
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./Root2'));
```

Comment: You pointed me to the right solution (for me). While your solution may work on most operating system, it does not currently on windows. If I am using nocase: true, I don't get any files back (which is not correct). With your answer I was able to find an explanation: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1144. Of couse, your answer is generally correct!